# In iOS development, can I read map traffic data?

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there a way to read map traffic data with iOS development? Basically I would like to see if I can determine if I am in a "Green Zone", "Yellow Zone" or "Red Zone" within the traffic layer. If I can't do it with Google Maps by itself, any recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google doesn't provide API level access to the traffic data, mainly due to licensing issues (Google doesn't own the data - it comes from various third party suppliers).

If you need access to it you'll need to approach the suppliers of traffic data for the country you're in, but from experience don't expect this to be particularly cheap.