# Using traffic information in iOS App

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to figure out if there are any way out there where I can read the traffic data based on the directions given from Point A to Point B.

I don't need to show the directions in the app. There are two things that would be nice to read, one is the amount of time to travel considering the current traffic situation; and/or read the traffic color (green = no traffic; red = trafic; etc.) on the direction's path.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try http://www.mapquestapi.com/traffic/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh441725

http://developer.yahoo.com/traffic/rest/V1/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is one reference regarding the question: They suggest that from google APIs this can not be achieved: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9350111/in-ios-development-can-i-read-map-traffic-data)
Then there are traffic information going to be available by Apple itself: "iOS 6 Maps uses TomTom mapping and traffic data"
I can not provide the way to use the Map framework for iOS 6 as it is in beta version. You have to figure out the way to use it.

Hope this helps.